# How can I assign a Dynamic UI Label value to server side string using on page load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I assign a Dynamic UI Label value to server side string using on page load? Here is my code

```
//Here asp Label
<html> 
    <body>
        <asp:Label ID="dynmcHiddenLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
//Javascript Code that assigning value on page load to Label
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        sliderIdentification();
    });
    function sliderIdentification() {
        var typename = $('#menu li.active a').attr('name');
        $('#ctl00_dynmcHiddenLabel').text(typename);
        $('#ctl00_dynmcHiddenLabel').val(typename);
    }
</script>
```

```csharp
//on server side - assigning label value to string value
string CategoryType = dynmcHiddenLabel.Text;
```

but i am getting `""` in CategoryType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. IMHO, you should really be using `asp:HiddenField` here.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="dynmcHiddenLabel" runat="server" />
```

Now if you are using ASP.NET 4 or above, please make use of [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="dynmcHiddenLabel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And call your function like this

```
function sliderIdentification() {
    var typename = $('#menu li.active a').attr('name');
    $('#dynmcHiddenLabel').val(typename);
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET VERSION 3.5 or below, make use of [inline expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) in ASP.NET like this

```
function sliderIdentification() {
    var typename = $('#menu li.active a').attr('name');
    $('#<%= dynmcHiddenLabel.ClientID %>').val(typename);
}
```

---

If you are particular about using `asp:Label`, then change the `.val` to `.html` like this

```
$('#<%= dynmcHiddenLabel.ClientID %>').html(typename);
```

Its because `asp:Label` is rendered as `span`

P.S: No need to change anything in code-behind.

Comment: still i am getting "" value in my code behind string.....i am assigning it on page load

Comment: edit the question and show me what you are doing in your code

Comment: I am using hidden Label itself and here is my code behind

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CategoryType = dynmcHiddenLabel.Value;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            
            
        }}

Comment: and i am getting the value in client side with out any problem...but on server side it's getting empty string

Comment: nothing wrong with the code dude. its because serverside `Page_Load` gets called before `DOMReady` of browser.

Comment: its not possible as client DOM ready and server page_load are independent events. but you can grab the value in button click event and all. whats the requirement